# Access refused for user rabbitmq & celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I create vhost:

```
rabbitmqctl add_vhost test
```

Then user:

```
rabbitmqctl add_user user 123456
```

Then I take permissions to that user:

```
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p test user "test" "test" "test"
```

I use Celery, in tasks.py:

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://user:123456@localhost/test', backend='amqp://user:123456@localhost/test')
```

Then I run:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

I have error:

```
amqp.exceptions.AccessRefused: Exchange.declare: (403) ACCESS_REFUSED - access to exchange 'celeryev' in vhost 'test' refused for user 'user'
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at set_permissions here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html#Access_control

When you call set_permissions you are passing "test" for configure, read and write, so your user will be able to only use a queue/exchange by the name "test"

Also, take a look at this link as well: https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Comment: Thanks. I try with `celeryev` in set_permissions and I have error with exchange `reply.celery.pidbox`, so now I use '.*' and it works. Does it save or I need to use regular expression 'celery'?

Comment: the regular expression needs to match the name of the queue/exchanges that you plan to create.

Answer (score 6):

If you still have error please check that you have correct double quotes (happened to me)

```
".*"
```

instead of

```
“.*”
```

To be sure, list permissions from users in your vhostpath (by default /)

```
rabbitmqctl list_permissions -p /
```

Answer (score 3):

As Lexsoul mentioned double quotes can be of wrong type, 
for example:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl list_permissions -p EDO_DEVELOPING
*Listing permissions in vhost "EDO_DEVELOPING" ...
billing “.*”    “.*”    “.*”
```

and did not work so I tried:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl clear_permissions -p EDO_DEVELOPING billing
Clearing permissions for user "billing" in vhost "EDO_DEVELOPING" ...

sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p EDO_DEVELOPING billing ".*" ".*" ".*"
Setting permissions for user "billing" in vhost "EDO_DEVELOPING" ...
```

then

```
sudo rabbitmqctl list_permissions -p EDO_DEVELOPING 
Listing permissions in vhost "EDO_DEVELOPING" ...
billing .*  .*  .*
```

And worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I reconfirm the previously details in regards to the grants.

**issue :**
caused a channel exception access_refused: access to exchange 'reply.celery.pidbox'

**solution :**
rabbitmqctl clear_permissions -p environment username
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p environment skberge ".*" ".*" ".*"